# DependencyResolver in ASP.NET Core. Also how to access HTTPConfiguration in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependencies, autofac, resolver

We are migrating our project from ASP.NET Web API to ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API as part of that we having following below lines of code.

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

The config is a `HTTPConfiguration` but while migrating to .NET 6.0 I was not able to access `HTTpConfiguration` from `WebApplicationBuilder` or `WebApplication`.

Please let me know how to access `HttpConfiguration` in .NET 6.0 and assign the `DependencyResolver`.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Core you don't explicitly set the dependency resolver and there's no HttpConfiguration. It's a whole different application and hosting model. I'd recommend following some of the tutorials about ASP.NET Core - it's similar, but different enough that the answer to this question would basically be to replicate all the existing migration docs and tutorials already on the Microsoft doc site.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out there is no `HttpConfiguration` anymore.

What you were looking for was probably a snippet like this one from [Microsoft / Code samples migrated to the new minimal hosting model in ASP.NET Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-7.0#aspnet-core-6-7):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());

// Register services directly with Autofac here. Don't
// call builder.Populate(), that happens in AutofacServiceProviderFactory.
builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder => builder.RegisterModule(new MyApplicationModule()));

var app = builder.Build();
```

Instead of using `builder.RegisterModule(new MyApplicationModule()` you can of course do the registering in any possible way, e. g. `builder.RegisterType<ConsoleLogger>().As<ILogger>();`

Other than that the autofac-examples on GitHub are also worth to have a look at, e. g. the [AspNetCore3NoStartupExample](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/blob/master/src/AspNetCore3NoStartupExample/Program.cs).